# How to export and import synapse dedicated Sql pool using ARM template

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-synapse

Step:1 I am trying to export the existing synapse sqlpool and trying to  deploy a new synapse sqlpool, but deployment failed with different errors like the server not found.

Step2: When I try with Microsoft azure deploy I am able create the synapse spool.

My question is what I missed in first step?

Is there any issue with using ARM template for export and import ?